# AngularJS view not updating after controller 'on' fired

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
joolaControllers.controller('dsCtrl', function ($scope, dsService, socket) {
  dsService.getList();
  socket.on('datasources/list:done', function (list) {
    $scope.list = list.datasources;  
  });
});
```

And the following service:

```
var joolaServices = angular.module('ngjoola.services', ['ngjoola']);
joolaServices.service('dsService', function (socket) {
  this.getList = function () {
    return joolaio.objects.datasources.list();
  };
});
```

`socket` is defined like this (joolaio.io.socket is a socket.io object):

```
ngjoola.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = joolaio.io.socket;
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

My HTML(jade):

```
.box-content(ng-controller="dsCtrl")
   | {{list}}
```

The list is not showing up.

Two questions:

1. Is this how I'm supposed to write services/controllers? Angular is very confusing in that sense.
2. Why is the `{{list}}` not showing?

Comment: What does `socket` look like?  I am guessing there is an inside/outside issue with the service you are dealing with, where in some cases, `$apply` is necessary and in other cases, it is not.  Can't say for sure without seeing the `socket` code.

Comment: Also, you most certainly don't want to be listening for socket responses in your controller.  You will want to structure the code to read more like `$scope.list = dsService.getList();` OR use promises: `dsService.getList().then(function(list) { $scope.list = list; });

Comment: @BrianGenisio I've added the socket code to my question. I tried wrapping this line ``$scope.list = list.datasources;`` with ``$apply`` but got an error message saying that $apply is already in progress..

Answer (score 0):

This was a callback issue, I updated my code to the following and it works now:

Controllers:

```
joolaControllers.controller('dsCtrl', function ($scope, dsService) {
  dsService.getList(function(list) {
    $scope.list = list;
  });
});
```

Service:

```
joolaServices.service('dsService', function (socket) {
  this.getList = function (callback) {
    joolaio.objects.datasources.list(function() {
      socket.on('datasources/list:done', function(list) {
        callback(list.datasources);
      })  
    });
  };
});
```